# How is the rule for sorting a list in ascending order and descending order?

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have been trying to understand how sorting using Comparable works. I have class Activity implementing Comparable interface. I am trying to understand how activity.finish-this.finish; sorts in descending order and how this.finish-activity.finish sorts in ascending order. I am confused about what to use first for sorting in ascending and descending?

```
class Activity implements Comparable {
    int start;
    int finish;

    public Activity(int start, int finish) {
        this.start = start;
        this.finish = finish;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) o;
        return  activity.finish-this.finish;
    }
}

public class ActivitySelectionProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int start[]  =  {1, 3, 0, 5, 8, 5};
        int finish[] =  {2, 4, 10, 7, 9, 9};

        List<Activity> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < start.length ; i++){
            list.add(new Activity(start[i], finish[i]));
        }

        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the `start` is not involved in the sorting? And what about collisions such as your last two objects both having a `finish` value of `9`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hacky. The contract for [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) is that it returns less than `0` when the result of comparison is less, greater than `0` when greater and `0` when equal. It is not obvious what the code does. Instead, I would use [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,%20int)) - something like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return Integer.compare(this.finish, ((Activity) o).finish);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) is correct. In addition, consider using `Comparator` rather than `Comparable` for your situation.

## tl;dr

```java
Collections.sort(                                       // Utility method for sorting a `List`. 
    activitiesAscending ,                               // A list copied from your original list of inputs.
    Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish )       // A predefined implementation of `Comparator` interface, built for comparing `int` values.    
);                                                      // Results in the passed list being modified, being sorted according to the logic of the passed `Comparator`. 

Collections.sort( 
    activitiesDescending , 
    Collections.reverseOrder(                           // Reverses the sorting logic of the passed `Comparator` object.
        Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish )   // Same `Comparator` as seen above.
    ) 
);
```

## `compareTo` consistent with `equals`

An additional problem is that if you read the Javadoc for [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html), you will see that generally it is best for the logic of `compareTo` to be be constant with the logic of `equals`.

But you want your comparing to be done only on the `finish` member field. So you should write your `equals` (and `hashCode`) to also focus solely on `finish`. But that would mean that your last two objects seen in the Question would be considered equal as they both share the value `9` for their `finish`. I expect you do not consider those two objects to be equal.

### `Comparator`

Defining a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) outside your class is likely more appropriate than making your `Activity` class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). We do just that in the rest of this Answer.

With Java 16, we can define your `Activity` class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395). The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Using `record` is not critical to this Answer, but makes the example code brief.

```java
package work.basil.example;

public record Activity( int start , int finish )
{
}
```

#### `Comparator.comparingInt`

Rather than define your own implementation of the `Comparator` interface, we can use the [predefined comparator for comparing `int` values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)).

We use a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) using the double COLON characters to name the method that should be used in retrieving an int from our objects being compared. That method reference is `Activity :: finish`. In records the default getter method is named the same as the property name, without the `get` prefix commonly seen à la JavaBeans. So simply `finish` as method name, not `getFinish`.

```java
Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish ) ) // Method reference from `Activity` being passed to `Comparator` built to compare `int` values.
```

Let's define your inputs using convenient [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E,E,E)) syntax.

```java
List < Activity > activities =
        List.of(
                new Activity( 1 , 2 ) ,
                new Activity( 3 , 4 ) ,
                new Activity( 0 , 10 ) ,
                new Activity( 5 , 7 ) ,
                new Activity( 8 , 9 ) ,
                new Activity( 5 , 9 )
        );
```

The list produced by that code is [unmodifiable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable). We want to sort a list, so we need a modifiable list. Feed that unmodifiable list to the constructor of a modifiable implementation of `List` such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```java
List < Activity > activitiesAscending = new ArrayList <>( activities );
```

Ask the utility method `Collections.sort` to sort that new list. Pass a `Comparator` as we showed earlier.

```java
Collections.sort( activitiesAscending , Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish ) );
```

For the opposite, in descending order with your `9` finishing objects first and your `2` finishing object last, we again call `Collections.sort`. But we pass a different `Comparator`. We pass our original `comparingInt` comparator to the utility method `Collections.reverseOrder` to produce a new comparator.

```java
List < Activity > activitiesDescending = new ArrayList <>( activities );
Collections.sort( activitiesDescending , Collections.reverseOrder( Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish ) ) );
```

Entire code example.

```java
List < Activity > activities =
        List.of(
                new Activity( 1 , 2 ) ,
                new Activity( 3 , 4 ) ,
                new Activity( 0 , 10 ) ,
                new Activity( 5 , 7 ) ,
                new Activity( 8 , 9 ) ,
                new Activity( 5 , 9 )
        );

List < Activity > activitiesAscending = new ArrayList <>( activities );
Collections.sort( activitiesAscending , Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish ) );

List < Activity > activitiesDescending = new ArrayList <>( activities );
Collections.sort( activitiesDescending , Collections.reverseOrder( Comparator.comparingInt( Activity :: finish ) ) );

System.out.println( "activities = " + activities );
System.out.println( "activitiesAscending = " + activitiesAscending );
System.out.println( "activitiesDescending = " + activitiesDescending );
```

When run.

```
activities = [Activity[start=1, finish=2], Activity[start=3, finish=4], Activity[start=0, finish=10], Activity[start=5, finish=7], Activity[start=8, finish=9], Activity[start=5, finish=9]]
activitiesAscending = [Activity[start=1, finish=2], Activity[start=3, finish=4], Activity[start=5, finish=7], Activity[start=8, finish=9], Activity[start=5, finish=9], Activity[start=0, finish=10]]
activitiesDescending = [Activity[start=0, finish=10], Activity[start=8, finish=9], Activity[start=5, finish=9], Activity[start=5, finish=7], Activity[start=3, finish=4], Activity[start=1, finish=2]]
```